# CakePHP plugin loading fails because of wrong path

Tags: cakephp

I encountered to a strange problem when trying to get webtechnick's Facebook plugin work with CakePHP:

```
 Error: Facebook.ConnectComponent could not be found.

 Error: Create the class ConnectComponent below in file: /home/$USER/www/CakePHP-project/Plugin/Facebook//Controller/Component/ConnectComponent.php
```

So it can't find that file because of wrong path. Plugin/Facebook//Controller/andSoOn...

What could be the problem here? I followed instructions carefully and I haven't found any typos.

EDIT:

From my AppController.php

```
    public $components = array('Facebook.Connect');
```

From BooksController.php

```
    public $helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook');
```

From bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('Facebook');
```

I use CakePHP 2.3.8. I have also Config/facebook.php-file but that is not important in this context.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. Besides, that, you didnt post any of the relevant code - how you included the component for instance.

Comment: You are using the right version of the plugin for your version of Cake?

Comment: I'm using this one: https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin I believe it should work, but I'm not sure.. @DavidYell

Comment: Webtechnick's Facebook plugin works with CakePHP 2.3.8 and I got bare CakePHP project work with Facebook Canvas. Only thing is that it won't work with my other project where I want to deploy it. It strangely have this path "/Plugin/Facebook//Controller/Component/ConnectComponent.php" when it tries to load that file. Why on earth? A routing problem? I haven't defined any custom routes... @mark